# How to declare a variable which tie an attribute to another one, in another node?

Tags: xslt

I need to declare a variable. I would like to link/tie 2 attributes in this variable.

```
<xsl:variable name="politiciens" select="Trans/Speakers/Speaker/@id='Trans/Episode/Section/Turn/@speaker'"/>`

    XSL =
    <xsl:for-each select="Trans/Speakers/Speaker[@check='yes']">
    <!-- declare a variable which contain @id, and whom will link/tie @speaker from Turn-->
    <xsl:variable name="politiciens" select="@id=//Turn/@Speaker" />
     <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
       td><xsl:value-of select="count(Trans/Episode/Section/Turn[@Speaker=$politiciens]/tour/motBDL[@lexeme='JE'])" /></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

XML =

```
<Trans scribe="ComputerName" audio_filename="Debat Hollande Sarkozy 1998" video_filename="" version="8" version_date="181221">
     <Speakers>
        <Speaker id="spk1" name="Nicolas Sarkozy" check="yes"/>
    </Speakers>
    <Episode>
        <Section type="report" startTime="0" endTime="1408.652">
          <Turn startTime="0" endTime="0.152">
            <Sync time="0"/>
          </Turn>
          <Turn speaker="spk1" startTime="0.152" endTime="3.038">
            <Sync time="0.152"/>
            <tour nbmots="14" id="000000">
              <motBDL lexeme="POUR">pour</motBDL>
    </tour>
    </Turn>
    </Section>
    </Episode>
    </Trans>
```

Expected = The two attributes to be linked together `<xsl:variable name="politiciens" select="@id='@speaker'"/>`

Answer (score 1):

I think it sounds like you need to read up on [keys](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/02/06/key-lookups.html). If you want to look-up the `Turn` elements for the current `Speaker` you can define a key like so

```
<xsl:key name="turns" match="Turn" use="@speaker" />
```

Then, within your `xsl:for-each` that gets the speakers, you can use the key to count the number of `turn` elements like so:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(key('turns', @id)/tour/motBDL)" />
```

(I've omitted the check on `@lexeme='JE'` because there isn't any matching value in your XML)

Try this XSLT as a starting point:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="turns" match="Turn" use="@speaker" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
      <xsl:for-each select="Trans/Speakers/Speaker[@check='yes']">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="count(key('turns', @id)/tour/motBDL)" /></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And, just as an example, you could also define a key to look up the `Speaker` elements themselves, if you want to list out the individual turns.

For example....

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="speakers" match="Speaker" use="@id" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
      <xsl:for-each select="Trans/Episode/Section/Turn[@speaker != '']">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="key('speakers', @speaker)/@name"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@startTime" /></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a part of my program, so in my XML there are plenty of  `lexeme="JE"`
And I have to do so with the `lexeme="JE"` `lexeme="TU"` etc..
My problem is :
`Trans/speakers/speaker/@id` and `Trans/Episode/section/Turn/tour/motBDL/@speaker`
equals to the same elements (spk1/spk2/spk3)
And I need to explain to my computer they are equals. A teacher told me it is doable with a code line `<xsl:variable select=""/>` + then including `Turn[@Speaker=$variable]` to the `<xsl:value-of select=""/>` and I can't figure out what or how. 
 A big thanks for helping me ! (I know I s*ck)

Comment: Without a key you would define your variable as `<xsl:variable name="speakerId" select="@id" />`, and then your count expression would be `count(/Trans/Episode/Section/Turn[@speaker = $speakerId]/tour/motBDL)`. But keys are the preferred solution as this is what they were designed for.

Comment: Oh. Thank you, I will keep it under my hat for some other work then !
Though I guess I have to do what my teacher told me to .
Thanks for everything !